# Making correct shapefile for Mapbox Studio in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, mapbox-studio

I want to create an age building map of my home city. I made decision to follow this tutorial: https://www.wired.com/2013/10/how-to-map-building-ages-in-your-home-town/.

Building footprint shapefile for my city was not placed in open sources and I tried to use OpenStreetMap data. Via the OSM Downloader plugin I downloaded the multipolygons, filtered buildings, added required attributes and saved a shapefile.

I uploaded this file to [this page](https://studio.mapbox.com/tilesets/) to convert it to a Mapbox Studio tileset (a zip archive with files `.shp, .shx, .dbf, .prj`). I am seeing error `Invalid zipfile` (and no more information).

I reprojected layer to `EPGS:3857`, changed type of this layer to `tile`, converted geometry to the singlepart but this error still showing.

Trying to use other formats (i. e., `kml`) I get a tileset in Studio but my attributes were deleted.

How to fix this error? I use QGIS 3.8.0 (Zanzibar)

Comment: What plugin allows you to modify OSM data and download it as a Mapbox Studio tileset?

Comment: @csk I use plugin OSM Downloader

Comment: Your workflow doesn't make sense. The OSM Downloader plugin just downloads all OSM data in a given area. You said you first downloaded the data using that plugin, then modified it, then downloaded it (again?) as a Mapbox Studio tileset. Where and how are you downloading it a second time?

Comment: @csk, drag and drop on this page: https://studio.mapbox.com/tilesets/

Comment: Microsoft opensourced building they created with their machine learning they have a geojson for each state on github it's now part of OSM too

Comment: Had a similar problem on Mac. Solved the issue by using WinZip and not the native archiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. The trouble was in zipper version, default GUI archiver in Ubuntu uses 2.0 version of zip, but Studio requires >2.0. Rezipping via console was helpful.

Comment: Same here. I had a problem on my macOS Catalina. Default zipper was causing this error. WinZip did the trick.